# Sizing resources with Kubernetes for GIS application

Tags: kubernetes, gis, postgis, geoserver

I am thinking to use the stack Geoserver, PostGIS, Openlayers, ReactJS for my GIS project. I also plan to deploy this solution on Kubernetes with AWS.

Questions:

Assume the traffic will be : 100 requests/s -> to 1000rq/s
What is the minimum resources (vCPU, RAM) for:
- Each node K8s
- Each Geoserver (pod)
- PostGIS

Is there any formula so I can apply to have that result?

Thank you in advance

Lp Ccmu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. It all depends on the footprint of all the different components of your specific application. I suggest you start small, gather a lot of metrics, and adjust.

Either grow or shrink depending on what you see on your metrics and make use of Kubernetes autoscaling tools like [HPAs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) and the cluster [autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler).

You can gather metrics using the AWS tools or something like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/). There are [many available resources](https://ramitsurana.gitbook.io/awesome-kubernetes/docs/projects/projects#monitoring-services) on how to use Prometheus to gather Kubernetes metrics on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. For GeoServer it depends on the type of data and the size and complexity of the data sets as well as they styling you are applying.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate APM, Elastic and kibana to have react app to send the metrics related API endpoints requests and page hits to monitor traffic. Based on data you can adjust your deployment's resources.

You can see this post for GIS stack on Kubernetes.

https://link.medium.com/r645NGwpejb